# QGIS Server WFS/WMS user and pass authentication

Tags: qgis, wfs, qgis-server, security, authentication

I configured a QGIS project as follows:

[image: QGIS configuration]

As you can see, QGIS Server is now serving two layers using WFS or WMS service. These two layers don't have the user/pass parameters saved in their layer configuration, so every time I open the project I am prompted to insert the user pass for the PostGIS connection (they are PostGIS layers):

[image]

---

Now we go to client (another computer) and I open a QGIS Client and I configure a new WFS connection introducing the user and password here (the user and password for the server to connect to PostGIS database):

[image]

I can see in the GetCapabilities request made by QGIS Client (captured using Fiddler proxy) that it is now adding authorization info in header:

[image]

If I try to connect to this new connection I get "there is no layer in service's capabilities".

I don't know if QGIS server is not binding the user/pass stored in HTTP's header to the QGIS project to connect the layers to PostGIS or what...

My goal is to be able to connect to QGIS Server using WMS/WFS services with different users and the server should connect to PostGIS with the user introduced in the client (this way I could in PostGIS know which user  is connected, making changes, and control what each user can or can't do)

Comment: did you find a way to resolve it?

Comment: no...i didnt...